# Preview issue on mac

Tags: mac, preview

Every time I open a pdf with preview, I get the spinning wheel and preview crashes.

I have seen online that I must delete the following:

```
Containers/com.apple.Preview
```

However, I am unsure if I should delete the entire folder or just its contents?